# Vscode multi-line edit/select on linux mint

Tags: visual-studio-code

I checked other questions/answers. Didn't seem to work out for me.

Back when I was running windows 10, I could simply hold **ctrl** and select  multiple lines. But since I moved to linux (Linux mint to be precise) that command doesn't seem to work. Also tried:

**alt** keyed and select. (didn't work) 
**ctrl+shift+alt** while selecting. Didn't work too.

Would appreciate if my question gets answered. Its kinda stressful to edit eaxh line separately.

Comment: search settings for `Multi Cursor Modifier`

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's just what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

You can use below key combination to edit multi lines in Visual Studio Code:

- *Linux*: Shift + Alt + Arrow Keys
- *Mac*: Opt + Cmd + Arrow Keys
- *Windows*: Ctrl + Alt + Arrow Keys

[Reference](https://kencenerelli.wordpress.com/2018/03/25/visual-studio-code-multi-line-and-multi-cursor-editing/)

Comment: Thanks. It does what it says but not quite what I want. In windows I was above to pinpoint where I want the multi select via clicking on the positions I want the cursors to be. Using the arrow keys, it's a lot harder to get that done.

Comment: Is there a way to force the same behavior in Windows/Linux? I'm used to using Shift + Alt in Linux but when I then switch over to Windows that same combination just moves the current line. My settings between Linux and Windows appear to be the same.

Comment: I believe there are ways to configure shortcut keys

Answer (score 4):

Press *Crtl+Shift+P*, search for "Toggle Multi-Cursor Modifier" and press *Enter*.
By [rioV8](/users/9938317/riov8)

Comment: I'm also using Linux Mint (deb) and this is the correct answer. In your settings switch "Multi-Cursor Modifier" to ctrlCMD and holding the control key will allow you to multi select. The problem for me on Linux was that the alt key (the default setting) disabled my mouse from selecting anything.

Comment: correct answer for Manjaro (arch) and works with ctrl + mouse select or ctrl + shift + arrow up/down

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did in Linux Mint 20.2:

1. Go to Preferences > Windows. In the Behavior tab, under Moving and Resizing Windows I have disabled Special key to move and resize windows. It was Alt by default.
2. In VSCode I set Alt as Keybinding for Toggle Multi-Cursor Modifier and it now works.

Comment: this did it but only when selecting upwards, weirdly.

Answer (score 1):

I went ahead and changed the following in the settings.json file.

[To change the settings.json file, see the following stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65909052)

```
"editor.selectionClipboard": false
```

If you do this, it will allow you on GNU/Linux Mint to use the middle mouse wheel to create multi cursors.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux Mint
Go to settings -> windows -> In the behavior tab for resizing windows Alt will be selected, disable it.
Come back to VS code, in the Setting Search toggle multi-cursor modifier ensure that it is in ALT, Now, you can use Alt + select to insert multicursor.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: But how can I leave Linux standard and change it in VSCode to use another modifier, like shift + alt + click?  
VSC doesn't appear to support changing it? I want to keep alt + click to move windows around in XFCE. 
There's the option to use Ctrl + click, weæll see what side effects that has.

Comment: This worked for me in Linux Mint. This was exactly what I was looking for. Now it works exactly like on my MS-windows machine. I don't need to move windows with alt+mouse, so... perfect!